# Determine whether this is a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Determine whether the following is a  subspace of $M_3(\Bbb F)$ or not
>
> $$W_B=\{A \in M_3(\Bbb F): AB = BA \}$$ where $B \in M_3(\Bbb F)$ is a fixed matrix.

Comment: It is a subspace and its proof is actually easy. Anyway, where you can stuck ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check the definition. $W_B \subseteq M_3(\mathbb{F})$ is clear. We have $W_B \neq \emptyset$, since $\mathcal{O} \in W_B: \mathcal{O}B=\mathcal{O}= \mathcal{O}B$,  where $\mathcal{O} \in M_3 ( \mathbb{F})$ denotes the zero matrix. Now let $A, A' \in W_B$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}$. Then we have

$$(A + A')B = AB + A'B = BA + BA' = B(A + A')$$

since we have distributivity when calculating with matrices over a field and $A$ and $A'$ commute with $B$. Finally, it is

$$(\alpha A)B = \alpha (AB) = \alpha (BA) = B (\alpha A).$$

So we conclude that $W_B$ is a subspace.